# Understanding this function () = the number of characters in , ∀ ∈ S

Tags: functions

S is described as a set containing all the words in the english dictionary.

```
() = the number of characters in , ∀ ∈ S
```

So, I'm figuring this function is returning the length of a string,

```
ie 'cat' 3, 'mathematics' 11, 'apple' 5
```

What I don't yet understand is the meaning of the end part:

```
∀ ∈ S
```

I did a search through my text book and the ∀ means 'for all'?, ∈ is short for 'elements' and S is the set. What does the ∀ means, with the little s? *For all elements in S represented as s?*

So would I be correct in thinking:

```
S = {'spaghetti', 'chips', 'coke'}
() = the number of characters in , ∀ ∈ S
would equal {9, 5, 4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall s \in S$ means "for all elements $s$ in the set $S$". Since $S$ is the set of words in the English dictionary, the elements are those words. Call such a word $s$. Then $\forall s \in S$ means, in English terms, "for every word in the English dictionary."

Thus, for any given word $s$, $L(s)$ returns the length of said word.

However, $L(s)$ does not define a set. Rather, the $\forall s \in S$ is merely stating the inputs for which $L$ is defined. Notably $L(S)$ would define a set in your line of thinking (known as the "image of $L$" or more precisely the "image of $S$ under $L$"), but that's neither here nor there for the moment.